# ¿Porque mi lista solo se carga con el mismo elemento aunque use findAll en JPA Spring Boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

estoy intentando traerme a mi aplicación una parte de la información de una vista creada en MYSql que es la siguiente vista

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED VIEW `BibliotecaPokemon`.`informacion_pokemon_movimiento` AS
select
    `p`.`nombre_p` AS `nombre_p`,
    `a`.`metodo` AS `metodo`,
    `a`.`numero` AS `numero`,
    `m`.`nombre_m` AS `nombre_m`,
    `m`.`poder` AS `poder`,
    `m`.`clase` AS `clase`,
    `t`.`nombre_t` AS `nombre_t`,
    `t`.`foto_t` AS `foto_t`
from
    (((`BibliotecaPokemon`.`pokemon` `p`
left join `BibliotecaPokemon`.`aprender` `a` on
    ((`p`.`nombre_p` = `a`.`aprender_pokemon_nombre_p`)))
left join `BibliotecaPokemon`.`movimiento` `m` on
    ((`a`.`aprender_movimiento_nombre_m` = `m`.`nombre_m`)))
left join `BibliotecaPokemon`.`tipo` `t` on
    ((`m`.`movimiento_tipo_nombre_t` = `t`.`nombre_t`)))
```

Para hacer esto de traer la información generé mi entidad con sus get, set y contructores además el Reposiroty de la siguiente manera

La entidad

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Informacion_Pokemon_Movimiento")
@Immutable
public class InformacionPokemonMovimiento {
    @Id
    @Column(name="Nombre_P")
    private String nombreP;
    @Column(name="Metodo")
    private String metodo;
    @Column(name="Numero")
    private Integer numero;
    @Column(name="Nombre_M")
    private String nombreM;
    @Column(name="Poder")
    private Integer poder;
    @Column(name="Clase")
    private String clase;
    @Column(name="Nombre_T")
    private String nombreT;
    @Column(name="Foto_T")
    private String fotoT;
}
```

y el Repository de la siguiente manera

```
@Repository
public interface IInformacionPokemonMovimientoDAO extends JpaRepository<InformacionPokemonMovimiento, String>{
    @Query("Select pm from InformacionPokemonMovimiento pm where pm.nombreP = ?1 order by pm.numero")
    List<InformacionPokemonMovimiento> BuscarPokemonMovimiento(String nombrePokemon);
    List<InformacionPokemonMovimiento> findByNombreP(String nombreP);
}
```

Como se ve en el Repository intente hacer dos métodos para traer la información filtrando por el campo NombreP, pero cuando los ejecuto y recorro la lista todos los objetos son el mismo como se ve en la foto donde está el código y la impresión de la lista

[image: Foto para la muestra de la ejecución del código]

Hago lo mismo con la otra función donde definí el @Query y me da el mismo resultado, no entiendo por qué, por eso espero a ver si alguien me podría ayudar, Gracias